# Tool-tips are not showing in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have put tooltips in my react app but not a single one of them showing. why is this? where is the fault lies? I 'll post the code here.

**TooltipSpan.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { OverlayTrigger } from 'react-bootstrap';

const TooltipSpan = (props) => {
  const { tooltip, className } = props;

  return (
    <OverlayTrigger placement="top" overlay={tooltip}>
      <span className={className} />
    </OverlayTrigger>
  );
};

export default TooltipSpan;
```

importing this to the below file.
**Like.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { OverlayTrigger, Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap';
import TooltipSpan from './TooltipSpan.js';

class Like extends Component {

  handleAddition = () => {
    this.props.onAddition();
  }

  handleDelete = () => {
    this.props.onDelete();
  }

  render() {
    const { isLiked, canLike, isBlocked, isReported } = this.props;
    const tooltipCannotLike = (
      <Tooltip id="cannot-like">You can not like a profile without a profile picture !</Tooltip>
    );
    const tooltipLike = (
      <Tooltip id="like">Like this profile to be able to talk to him. He also like you !</Tooltip>
    );

    if (isBlocked || isReported) {
      return <span className="fa fa-star cannot-like" />;
    }
    if (!canLike) {
      return <TooltipSpan className="fa fa-star cannot-like" tooltip={tooltipCannotLike} />;
    }
    if (isLiked) {
      return <button className="fa fa-star liked" onClick={this.handleDelete} />;
    }
    return (
      <OverlayTrigger placement="bottom" overlay={tooltipLike}>
        <span>
          <button
            className="fa fa-star-o"
            onClick={this.handleAddition}
          />
        </span>
      </OverlayTrigger>
    );
  }
}

export default Like;
```

Like.js is one file. I have a block and report js files, and not a single tooltips working in those files too.
I have one question. Does the building the app fix the issues like this? I haven't yet built this app.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error on `TooltipSpan.js`. You should close your `span` like this `<span className={className}>Some text</span>`

I've reproduced it on here on [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-leftpad-p1jte?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: i tried it but actually not working. I dont want to add an extra text to it. i just want to use the added icon as the text. as you can see i have already added an icon on the page which is fa fa-star and that is equivalent to that 'some text' you added. when you clicked on that start you like is generated. but its in the like.js file. when someone hovers on it it should be displayed. how can I link it to the overlaytrigger? I tried doing <span className={className}> {className} </span> but wont work.

Comment: @necrofxk To get this straight, the tooltip is actually working on hover. The issue right now is on how you import your font-awesome. You didn't specify how you import your icons so I can't really help you on that. I would suggest you to use `@fortawesome/react-fontawesome` to make it easier for you to use `fontawesome` with react. Read it up on their [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome) on how to add it to you project. I've updated the above [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-dhawan-4ix2t) with those packages.